# The FunctionImport 'GetEmployee' could not be found in the container 'CtxDb'

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a `stored procedure` by using `Linq`. For that I wrote this code:

```
 public class CtxDb:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
        public virtual ObjectResult<Employee> GetEmployee()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Employee>("GetEmployee");
        }
    }
```

When I'm calling my sp from `Web API` I'm getting an error:

> The FunctionImport 'GetEmployee' could not be found in the container
>   'CtxDb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualify the function import with the container name like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Employee> GetEmployee()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Employee>("EntityContainerName.GetEmployee");
        }
```

The entity container name is found on your EDMX - right click anywhere and do "Properties".

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892926/entity-framework-4-pocos-stored-procedure-error-the-functionimport-could-not)

Alternative way:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Employee> GetEmployee() {
     return this.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("GetEmployee"); 
}
```

Comment: Error as Additional information: The FunctionImport 'GetEmployee' could not be found in the container 'CtxDb'.

Comment: Here im not using any .Edmx file

Comment: You can also try this solution : return this.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("GetEmployee"). Or ExecuteSqlCommand("exec StoreProcedure_Name)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
public virtual IEnumerable<GetProductCategoryList_Result> GetProductCategoryList(Nullable<int> userID)
{
    var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
        new SqlParameter("UserID", userID) :
        new SqlParameter("UserID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

    //return this.Database.SqlQuery<GetProductCategoryList_Result>("GetProductCategoryList @UserID", userIDParameter).ToList();
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<GetProductCategoryList_Result>("osa.GetProductCategoryList @UserID", userIDParameter);
}
```

Comment: Please add some description

Comment: This helps me, because I'm using parameters. Thanks.